# Problems with DevForce queries within a checked context

Tags: c#, expression-trees, integer-overflow, devforce

We are in the process of switching over our codebase to have the [Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) option turned on by default and we've run into problems with our DevForce queries.

I'm able to reproduce the problem with a very basic query such as this against the NorthwindIB database:

```
var coolProducts = em.Products.Where(p => p.UnitsInStock == 42).Execute();
```

By doing some debugging, it looks like DevForce is trying to add that query to the cache which involves making a hash code for the query.  The class that does that hash code generation (`ExpressionHashCodeCalculator`) is missing a switch case for the `ConvertChecked` `ExpressionType` and so it throws an `ArgumentException` saying "Unknown Expression type".

It seems the compiler sprinkles that ConvertChecked thing all over the place in expressions when you are running in a checked context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  It will be fixed in the next release, due in March.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Any ideas when in March the release might be?  Early in March, late in March....?

Comment: Target is early March, but may slip.

Comment: Has there been any update on this release?  We aren't in desperate need of it but are still curious.

Comment: We did slip... but the plan is to have it out next week.  The release will support Windows 10 Universal apps, and that's caused a few issues for us.   The fix for this checked build bug is in the release.

Comment: We've just released version 7.4.0, which includes a fix for this and your bug report on the memory leak.

Comment: We've upgraded to the latest version and it appears all the `checked` issues are fixed.  Thanks!